# Reassigning Variables in Tensorflow and scope

Tags: python, tensorflow, rotational-matrices

I'm trying to understand the difference between why one of these implementations works, and one doesn't.  I'm trying to represent some geometry in tensorflow.

First, a helper file, d_math.py

## !/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

dtype = tf.float64

```
def skew_symmetric(vector):
    #Creates a tensorflow matrix which is a skew-symmetric version of the input vector    
    return tf.stack([(0., -vector[2], vector[1]), (vector[2], 0., -vector[0]), (-vector[1], vector[0], 0.)], axis=0)
```

Here is implementation 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import d_math as d
import math
import time


class Joint():
    def __init__(self, axis, pos): #TODO: right now only revolute:
        axis_ = tf.Variable(axis, dtype=d.dtype)
        axis_ /= tf.linalg.norm(axis)
        theta_ = tf.Variable(0.0, dtype=d.dtype) #Always at the 0 angle config
        self.theta_ = theta_
        self.R_ = tf.cos(theta_) * tf.eye(3, dtype=d.dtype) + d.skew_symmetric(axis_) + (1. - tf.cos(theta_)) * tf.einsum('i,j->ij', axis_, axis_)
        


joint = Joint(np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0]), 0.0)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()    

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)    
    print(joint.R_)
    print(joint.R_.eval())
    joint.theta_ = joint.theta_.assign(math.pi/4.)
    session.run(joint.theta_)
    print(joint.R_.eval())
```

The above version updates theta, and then I get the evaluation of two rotation matrices, one for theta = 0, and one for theta = pi/4.

I then tried to refactor my code a bit, adding a global session variable, created in a separate file, and hiding away as much about tensorflow as I could for now in the API:

version 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import d_math as d
import math
import time
import session as s


class Joint():
    def __init__(self, axis, pos): #TODO: right now only revolute:
        axis_ = tf.Variable(axis, dtype=d.dtype)
        axis_ = axis_ / tf.linalg.norm(axis)
        theta_ = tf.Variable(0.0, dtype=d.dtype) #Always at the 0 angle config
        self.theta_ = theta_
        self.R_ = tf.cos(theta_) * tf.eye(3, dtype=d.dtype) + d.skew_symmetric(axis_) + (1. - tf.cos(theta_)) * tf.einsum('i,j->ij', axis_, axis_)
        
    def set_theta(self, theta):
        self.theta_.assign(theta)
        s.session.run(self.theta_)
        

joint = Joint(np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0]), 0.0)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()    

with s.session as session:
    session.run(init)  
    print(joint.R_)
    print(joint.R_.eval())
    #joint.theta_ = joint.theta_.assign(math.pi/4.)
    joint.set_theta(math.pi/4.)
    print(joint.R_.eval())
```

session.py can be seen here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tensorflow as tf

session = tf.Session()
```

This gives the R matrix with theta = 0 for both evaluations.

Can someone please explain to me why implementation 2 isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.assign` returns a reference of the updated variable. According to the docs: `Returns: A Tensor that will hold the new value of 'ref' after the assignment has completed.`

In the first example, you're actually using the updated reference:

```
joint.theta_ = joint.theta_.assign(math.pi/4.)
session.run(joint.theta_)
print(joint.R_.eval())
```

In the second example you're not using the updated reference:

```
 def set_theta(self, theta):
    not_used = self.theta_.assign(theta)
    s.session.run(self.theta_)
```

My best guess is that if you use the updated reference, it should work:

```
def set_theta(self, theta):
    self.theta_ = self.theta_.assign(theta)
    s.session.run(self.theta_)
```

Also it would be wise to not overwrite original tensor references, so I would create a new attribute for the updated var:

```
def set_theta(self, theta):
    self.theta_updated_ = self.theta_.assign(theta)
    s.session.run(self.theta_updated_)

# ...
print(self.theta_updated_.eval())  # <<< This should give you updated value
```

**Important**: However running `print(joint.R_.eval())` MAY NOT give you the updated value still because the operation `self.R_` is not enforced to depend on the updated reference `self.theta_updated_` and you may have to use `tf.control_dependencies` to enforce execution of `self.R_` operation only after the update is done. For example:

```
with tf.control_dependencies([self.theta_updated_]):
    self.R_ = tf.cos(theta_) * # ...
```

**Final Note**: Assigning values to variables doesn't automatically tell other operations that they need to wait until this assignment is done. I discovered this the hard way. Here's a few [snippets](https://gist.github.com/nitred/34f9f7bb5d405b8cfc170f85b28c8b65#file-tf_sharing_variables-md) that I wrote that trace how the variables behave when tf.assign is being used. I recommend going carefully through the snippet called: `Optimizing original variables that have been updated using tf.assign`. The snippets are self contained.

Comment: Thank you for this very informative answer.  Can you please elaborate on why it's bad to overwrite original tensor references?  Rather than having a never-ending supply of references (something I don't want to do) as I continually update a value downstream, how can I update a variable otherwise?

Comment: I'm not really an expert at this but I imagine that tensorflow is designed for use cases where the graph is fixed at some point and you keep reusing the graph. Using `tf.assign` operations creates new nodes in the graph (if I'm not mistaken) and therefore the graph is ever exanding. So if your use case involves setting the value of `self.theta_` from an external source, then using `self.theta_ =  tf.placeholder()` along with `sess.run([joint.R_], feed_dict={self.theta_=math.pi/4.})` is a far better approach.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I will refactor this code to use placeholders.